# MongoDB performance slow due to all memory being used used on EC2 instance

Tags: java, memory, mongodb, amazon-ec2, ram

We have created mongodb sharding on EC2 having with 3 servers of m2-xlarg each and 1 instance of m2xlarge as configdb and mongos.

We have done a test to insert 110 million documents. Each document size is 0.3 KB. It is giving the desired result of 55,000 write per second.

However, we have observed that as soon as the memory usage approaches 15GB (the instance's RAM amount), Mongo's insertion performance drops to 1000 inserts per second, and then it slowly stops taking any new insertion requests.

Assuming that the cache is using all of the RAM, that performance issue is understandble.

We had rebooted all the servers though, and after restarting, we still observed that mongo was not performing very slowly after the first few hundred inserts.

Can anyone please let us know what could be the problem here?

We assumed that when the Mongo cache size approaches the instance's RAM limit (and thus is using all of the RAM), that the performance would suffer.  We are, however, surprised that performance does not recover once the servers are restarted and memory is freed up.

Comment: You should provide more details. What's the output of `mongostat` during that period? Also `iostat -x 2`.

Comment: I have pasted statistic here : http://pastie.org/private/b6zpyqh1hiugyij6jvldfg

Comment: It's interesting. Why your shard 3 has that high %iowait? Is it the primary shard for the database?

Comment: No primary server is shard 1.

Comment: AWS IO is not only slow, but unpredictable since it's a resource shared with many other tenants.  Could be the IO channel to that particular EC2 instance is saturated from other customer's activities.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, EC2 IO performance is very poor relative to other solutions.  MongoDB runs extremely fast when everything is in RAM, but relies on very fast IO to continue to perform well when the collections including indices no longer fit in RAM.

I suggest measuring your EC2 instance's IO performance.

If you have not already, you can significantly improve EC2's IO by striping a number of EBS volumes into a RAID configuration.  Still, I expect it will be slow compared to e.g. a dedicated SAN.

If you cannot get adequate IO from EC2, your options are probably to use more instances to keep things in RAM, or move off of EC2.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. In the light of our problem right now we are just dumping the documents which would not be queried in near future as of now. After restarting all the servers it should take a new document to write but still it is not taking a new write request. What could be the problem?

Comment: If by dumping documents you mean issuing MongoDB commands to remove them, it can actually take a long time for your nodes to rebalance and/or update indices (to reflect the deletions) if you are out of RAM and IO is very slow.

Comment: thanks eric. here dumping means we are only inserting documents.